Apply method in my AuthenticationFilter not getting called
I don't know why but my apply method inside my AuthenticationFileter is not getting called, even though I hitting the routes
my AuthenticationFilter
@Component("Authenticate")
@Slf4j
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthenticationFilter.Config>{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private RouteValidator routeValidator;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    
    private final Auth_Manager_Service authManagerFeignClient;
    
    public AuthenticationFilter(@Lazy Auth_Manager_Service authManagerFeignClient) {
        super(Config.class);
        this.authManagerFeignClient = authManagerFeignClient;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!AuthenticationFilter initialized and registered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    
    public static class Config {}   

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        
        return ((exchange, chain)->{
            logger.debug("\nEnter Authentication Filter");
            
            ServerHttpRequest httpRequest = null;
                    
                logger.debug("\n--- Authentication Filter Debug Information ---");
                logger.debug("Request URL: {}", exchange.getRequest().getURI());
                logger.debug("Request Headers: {}", exchange.getRequest().getHeaders());
                logger.info("Processing request: {} {}", exchange.getRequest().getMethod(),exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath());
                
                
                        logger.debug("\n{}",routeValidator.isSecured.test(exchange.getRequest()));
                        if (routeValidator.isSecured.test(exchange.getRequest())) {

                                //header contains token or not
                                if (!exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
                                    logger.error("Missing or invalid authorization header");
                                    throw new RuntimeException("Missing authorization header");
                                }
                                
                                
                                
                                String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);       //it's a token
                                System.out.println("Token: "+authHeader);
                                logger.error("Token: {}",authHeader);
                                
                                if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                                    authHeader = authHeader.substring(7);
                                }
                                try {
                                    System.out.println("Checking if it even reach here?");
                                    jwtUtil.validateToken(authHeader);
                                    logger.debug("Auth Header: {}", authHeader);
                                    System.out.println("authHeader: "+authHeader);
                                    
                                    
                                    String username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(authHeader);
                                    System.out.println("username: "+username);
                                    
                                    List<String> roles = authManagerFeignClient.getRolesByUsername(username);
                                    System.out.println("roles: "+roles);
                                    
                                    String rolesAsString = String.join(",", roles);
                                    System.out.println("roles: "+rolesAsString);
                                    
                                    
                                    logger.debug("Authenticated User: {}", username);
                                    logger.debug("User Roles: {}", rolesAsString);

                                    httpRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                                             .header("loggedInUser", jwtUtil.extractUsername(authHeader))
                                             .header("loggedInUserRoles", rolesAsString)        // Only for now as we are taking roles as single value and not as list
                                             .build();
                                    logger.debug("Header Info: {}", httpRequest);
                                            
                                } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                                    logger.error("JWT token has expired", e);
                                    throw new RuntimeException("JWT token has expired", e);
                                } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                                    logger.error("JWT token is malformed", e);
                                    throw new RuntimeException("JWT token is malformed", e);
                                } catch (SignatureException e) {
                                    logger.error("JWT signature is invalid", e);
                                    throw new RuntimeException("JWT signature is invalid", e);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    logger.error("Invalid access: Unauthorized access to application", e);
                                    System.out.println("Invalid access...!");
                                    throw new RuntimeException("!!Unauthorized access to application!!");
                                }
                        }
            
            logger.debug("---------------------------\n");
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(httpRequest).build());
        
        });
    }
}

my GatewayConfig
    @Bean
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, AuthenticationFilter authFilter) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route("Gateway", r -> r
                .path("/api/gateway/v1/user-info")  // The specific path to route
                .filters(f -> f.filter(authFilter.apply(new AuthenticationFilter.Config())))
                .uri("http://localhost:8084"))
            .build();
    }

when I am trying to hit api: /api/gateway/v1/user-info, any of the log or system.out.println present apply method in authentionFilter is showing.

anything inside: public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) is not getting called

any help anybody??
